# Nothing is showing on custom view.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, module, customer, customer-account

I am developing an e-commerce website for my boutique. For this i want to add a custom option of "My measurements" in customer account section.

I have created a module. I added a file in `app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/layout/mymodule.xml`.

And the code is....

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <module_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="module/module" name="module" />
        </reference>
    </module_index_index>
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="module">
                <name>viewmodule</name>
                <path>module/customer/view</path>
                <label>module</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
    <module_customer_view>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="module" name="view.module" template="module/customer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </module_customer_view>
</layout>
```

and Created a template file in `app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/template/mymodule/customer/view.phtml`

And added some random text on `view.phtml`.

But the problem is nothing is showing on my `view.phtml`. Can anybody help me ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Measure_Amsize>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Measure_Amsize>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <Amsize>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Measure_Amsize</module>
                    <frontName>Amsize</frontName>
                </args>
            </Amsize>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Amsize>
                    <file>Amsize.xml</file>
                </Amsize>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
     <admin>
        <routers>
            <Amsize>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Measure_Amsize</module>
                    <frontName>Amsize</frontName>
                </args>
            </Amsize>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <Amsize module="Amsize">
                <title>Amsize</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>                
                <children>
                    <items module="Amsize">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>Amsize/adminhtml_Amsize</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </Amsize>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Amsize>
                            <title>Amsize Module</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </Amsize>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>    
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Amsize>
                    <file>Amsize.xml</file>
                </Amsize>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>     
    <global>
        <models>
            <Amsize>
                <class>Measure_Amsize_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>Amsize_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </Amsize>
            <Amsize_mysql4>
                <class>Measure_Amsize_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <Amsize>
                        <table>Amsize</table>
                    </Amsize>
                </entities>
            </Amsize_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <Amsize_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Measure_Amsize</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </Amsize_setup>
            <Amsize_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </Amsize_write>
            <Amsize_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </Amsize_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <Amsize>
                <class>Measure_Amsize_Block</class>
            </Amsize>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <Amsize>
                <class>Measure_Amsize_Helper</class>
            </Amsize>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

This is my config.xml file where Measure is namespace and Amsize is module name.

Comment: Is it the error or a typo: <modulename_index_index> ... </module_index_index> ?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau  It was a typo. I have made the correction.

Comment: Please share your module config file as well

Comment: @Arunendra Added config.xml code.

Comment: Is your layout file named `Amsize.xml` with capital A?

Comment: Does the block class referenced in `<block type="module" name="view.module" template="module/customer/view.phtml"/> ` inherit from `Mage_Core_Block_Template`?

Comment: yes @JanPapenbrock my layout file is Amsize.xml with capital A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected your module try following codes:

**app/code/local/Measure/Amsize/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Measure_Amsize>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Measure_Amsize>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <amsize>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Measure_Amsize</module>
                    <frontName>Amsize</frontName>
                </args>
            </amsize>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <amsize>
                    <file>amsize.xml</file>
                </amsize>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
     <admin>
        <routers>
            <amsize>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Measure_Amsize</module>
                    <frontName>amsize</frontName>
                </args>
            </amsize>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <amsize module="amsize">
                <title>Amsize</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>                
                <children>
                    <items module="amsize">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>amsize/adminhtml_amsize</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </amsize>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <amsize>
                            <title>Amsize Module</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </amsize>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>    
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <amsize>
                    <file>amsize.xml</file>
                </amsize>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>     
    <global>
        <models>
            <amsize>
                <class>Measure_Amsize_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>Amsize_mysql4</resourceModel-->
            </amsize>
            <amsize_mysql4>
                <class>Measure_Amsize_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <amsize>
                        <table>amsize</table>
                    </amsize>
                </entities>
            </amsize_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <amsize_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Measure_Amsize</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </amsize_setup>
            <amsize_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </amsize_write>
            <amsize_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </amsize_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <amsize>
                <class>Measure_Amsize_Block</class>
            </amsize>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <amsize>
                <class>Measure_Amsize_Helper</class>
            </amsize>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Your controller file code:
**app/code/local/Measure/Amsize/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class Measure_Amsize_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function IndexAction() {      

      $this->loadLayout(); 
      $this->renderLayout(); 

    }
}
```

your block file:

```
**app/code/local/Measure/Amsize/Model/Amsize.php**
<?php   
class Measure_Amsize_Block_Index extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{   

    public function index(){
        echo 'hello';
    }

}
```

Helper file :

```
**app/code/local/Measure/Amsize/Helper/Data.php**    
<?php
class Measure_Amsize_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

your layout file:
**app/design/frontend/themepackage/theme/layout/amsize.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
      <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="amsize">
                <name>viewmodule</name>
                <path>amsize/index</path>
                <label>amsize</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
    <amsize_index_index>
              <reference name="content">
            <block type="amsize/index" name="amsize_index" template="amsize/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </amsize_index_index>
</layout>
```

Your template file:
**app/design/frontend/themepackage/theme/template/amsize/view.phtml**

```
<?php 
echo $this->index();

?>
```